# wget installed from Homebrew SSL errors

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, homebrew, wget

My version of `wget` installed via Homebrew is throwing errors when downloading files, related to OpenSSL certs. Here's an example (happens on any URL attempted to download via `wget`):

```sh
wget https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.6/ruby-2.6.3.tar.bz2
--2019-09-16 22:39:54--  https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.6/ruby-2.6.3.tar.bz2
Resolving cache.ruby-lang.org (cache.ruby-lang.org)... 151.101.1.178, 151.101.65.178, 151.101.129.178, ...
Connecting to cache.ruby-lang.org (cache.ruby-lang.org)|151.101.1.178|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify cache.ruby-lang.org's certificate, issued by ‘CN=GlobalSign CloudSSL CA - SHA256 - G3,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,C=BE’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to cache.ruby-lang.org insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

I've tried fully uninstalling (with `--force`) `wget` and `openssl` and reinstalling, to no avail. I can't figure out what else to try that could lead to the culprit issue. This seems to be limited to `wget`, since downloading exactly the same thing via `curl` works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide the output of `wget -V`. And redo the download with `wget --verbose <url>`.

Comment: @Simba: `--verbose` and `wget -V` output added as requested.

Answer (score 0):

This might actually have nothing to do with your `wget` or `brew` installations. Perhaps you are getting this error because there is something wrong with how the certificate is sent from the server?

You can try using the `--no-check-certificate` switch:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.6/ruby-2.6.3.tar.bz2
```

If you experience further problems, I would suggest that you try to reinstall `wget`:

```
brew reinstall wget
```